# Rails form create is not seeing the parameter passed to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

Thanks for reading, new to rails but trying to build a form to pass parameters. However, after the parameters are entered into the form, the validation in the create page is not seeing it, and gives me an error. But the logs show that the parameter was entered... I'm using the simple_form gem as well.

Controller:

class FoundsController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @found = Found.all
  end

  def new
    @found = Found.new
  end

  def create
    @found = Found.new(found_params)
    if @found.save
        redirect_to "/founds#index"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end

 def found_params
    params.require(:floc).permit(:ftitle, :fdescription, :fcontact)
end
```

New Form Page:

```
<h1>Founds#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/founds/new.html.erb</p>

<%= simple_form_for @found do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :floc, label: "floc" %>
  <%= form.input :fcontact, label: "fcontact" %>
  <%= form.input :fdescription, label: "fdescription" %>
  <%= form.input :ftitle, label: "ftitle" %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Error: param is missing or the value is empty: floc

```
def found_params
    params.require(:floc).permit(:ftitle, :fdescription, :fcontact)
end


Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bJ1bUhd3G8z4S1QV+XsEAHmOcdSQyQxVS0rOSAsq6YANvz9ED7lFTME6falij4nrXkWEypWsSnPW7k9YHFGhDQ==",
 "found"=>{"floc"=>"location",
 "fcontact"=>"contact",
 "fdescription"=>"descript",
 "ftitle"=>"title"},
 "commit"=>"Create Found"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine except for the strong parameters

It should be `params.require(:found).permit(:floc, :ftitle, :fdescription, :fcontact)`

You are telling Rails that the params coming in must have the `:found` key, nested under which are the params you actually care about. Of those parameters, only the ones that are permitted will get through. Params that are not permitted will not get through but not throw an error.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, that works I was missing the key, my assumption was that that .require(floc) meant that I cannot pass form without floc parameter... not including or defining the strong parameter piece gave me the same error as well.